# Add font awesome icon to rails submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I have a f.submit in a form. I want to add a font awesome icon to it. But Im not able to.

```
<%= f.submit "Register", class: "button my-button", id: "register-button" %>
```

how can I add a font awesome icon `<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>` to it ??

Comment: how did install it gem or cdn ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

another alternative is `button_tag`

```
<%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "button my-button", id: "register-button" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

With gem font-awesome

```
<%= f.button fa_icon("lock", text: "Register"), class: "button my-button", id: "register-button" %>
```

With plain Rails:

```
 <%= f.button'<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register'.html_safe, class: "button my-button", id: "register-button" %>
```

Comment: I tried the plain rails method. It gives me the whole `<i class=....register` written inside the button